# Column getting lost in LINQ with Method Syntax after group by

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm pretty new to LINQ and trying to figure it out. I have the following statement:

```
Context.dataset1
    .Join(
        Context.dataset2, 
        r => r.ID, o => o.ID, 
        (r, o) => new  { PartID = r.PartID, Quantity = r.Quantity1 - r.Quantity2, Date = o.Date })
    .GroupBy(
        column => new { column.Date }, 
        (key, group) => new {Date = key.Date, Quantity = group.Sum(g => g.Quantity) })
    .Where(x => x.Quantity > 0);
```

the return data set looks like this

```
| Date          | Quantity |
| ------------- | ---------|
| 2022-01-01    | 333      |
| 2022-01-02    | 444      |
| 2022-03-03    | 444      |
```

what i want it to look like is

```
| PartID |          Date | Quantity |
|--------| ------------- | ---------|
|1       | 2022-01-01    | 333      |
|1       | 2022-01-02    | 444      |
|2       | 2022-03-03    | 444      |
```

Basically it seems that when I do the groupby I lose access to the PartId column since i'm no specifying it inside the groupby. I'm not sure how to make it appear without grouping by it which I don't want to do.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What if two different part ids exist for the same date?  What part id would it show?  If you _really_ want the part id, then you need to include the part id in your group by.  i.e. `column => new { column.PartID, column.Date }`.

Comment: Please show the class model, we have to understand the relationships (and why don't you use a navigation property instead of `Join`?) Also, tag the EF version you're using.

Comment: Why JOINs? The whole point of using EF or any ORM is to work with objects in the application and have the ORM generate the SQL statements. A DbSet isn't a dataset, it's an Entity placeholder. If you have an `Order` entity with parts, there should be an `Order.Parts` property as well. EF itself will map the `Order` and `Part` entities and generate the JOINs

Comment: With `Order.Parts`, the query could be as simple as `context.Orders.Select(o=>new {o.Date,Quantity=o.Parts.Sum(p=>p.Quantity1 - p.Quantity2)})`.

Comment: @KirkWoll your comment was the answer, I needed to group by part id to solve that underlying issue which then solved the issue i was asking about as well. if you make it an answer i will give you solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if two different part ids exist for the same date? What part id would it show? If you really want the part id, then you need to include the part id in your group by. For example:

```
column => new { column.PartID, column.Date }
```

This will mean that if you have multiple part ids for the same date, you will have as many rows for that date as you have distinct part ids.  Based on your comments, this seems like what you're after.